# uptime | awk -F: '{print $NF}' - What happens here?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, awk

Can someone explain me what happens here?

```
uptime | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
```

- -F: field separator
- $NF: number of fields in the current line

I don't understand why this command result in the same result as

```
uptime | awk -F: '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-F` (`--field-separator fs`) `-F:` makes `:` the *input field separator*.

We could take the output of an example `uptime` and split it into fields separated by `:`:

```
 09:03:24 up 32 days,  1:32,  3 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.09, 0.08
 -- -- ----------------- --------------------------- -----------------
 1  2          3                      4                      5
```

It's easy to say that the fields 1-4 are pretty pointless by themselves, but the 5th field gives us just the *load averages*. But this doesn't work all the time, as an hour earlier it would have been the 4th field:

```
 08:03:24 up 32 days, 32 min, 3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
 -- -- --------------------------------------------- -----------------
 1  2                        3                               4
```

Here, the `$NF` comes to help, as it will always give the number of fields: in the first case it would have been equal to `$5`, but in the second case `$4`.

Putting it all together, **`| awk -F: '{print $NF}'` always gives everything after the last `:`**.

Comment: Thank you very much! :). But I don't understand why this topic has been closed. I see here several questions about awk...

Comment: How can I get everything BEFORE the last `:`?

Comment: `| awk -F: '{$NF=""; print $0}'`

Comment: `NF` always give the total number of splited fields

Answer (score 0):

Good explanation by Esa Jokinen, I am giving you one example not to use specific column number in case of uptime (Examples are from MAC system).

```
$ uptime
16:12  up 25 days,  2:48, 15 users, load averages: 3.41 3.20 3.11
```

Check how many fields.

```
$ uptime | awk -F: '{print NF}'
4
```

Now if you use $NF it will gives you desired results but $5 will not.

```
$ uptime | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
3.96 3.31 3.15
```

The `-F fs` option defines the input field separator to be the regular expression `fs`. So here `:` is just a separator to divide into columns.

Comment: What does this add to my answer? :)